# Switch py2exe 64bit to 32bit

Tags: python, uninstallation, py2exe

I'm trying to switch my 64bit py2exe to 32bit version. Since I haven't found any uninstall command for py2exe, I've decided to just install 32bit version without uninstalling previous 64bit version.

Is this process harmless?

EDIT: I want to install 32bit py2exe to make an 32bit program.

Comment: probably not. if you nuke the 64bit version and don't replace ALL of the modules/libraries/whatever with 32bit versions (e.g. you have extra optional bits installed), then you're going to end up with a broken install and broken code due to those "missing" libraries.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc. Is there a clean way to uninstall py2exe 64bit please?

Answer (score 0):

py2exe ist a Python library.  It uses the Python it is installed for.

So, it seems you need to install 32-bit Python (NOT into the same directory as ths 64-bit Python!), and then install the py2exe in it, and you should be ready to go.